# Web.py mod_wsgi autoreload

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, web.py

I am running the latest version of web.py with mod_wsgi and have this in my code:

`application = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=True).wsgifunc()`

It is autoreloading most of the time but every so often I need to go to the command line and restart Apache myself. Any idea why it is not always "autoreloading"?

Details:

```
Apache 2.2.12
Python 2.6
web.py 0.33
mod_wsgi 3.1
```

Comment: What is the top-level WSGI script?  Are you "touching" this top-level wsgi script file?

Comment: Don't think so, I followed the web.py tutorial at http://webpy.org/install#apachemodwsgi to get it running. Never edited a wsgi script file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on the internal web.py reloading mechanism under Apache/mod_wsgi as not likely to work properly if at all. Disable the web.py reloading mechanism if you have enabled it in some way, and then read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

This explains how reloading works under Apache/mod_wsgi.

In short, use mod_wsgi daemon mode and after changes touch the WSGI script file.